# Find subdocuments in MongoDB that are values of name/value pair rather than array elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Perhaps my document structure is not well suited for what I am trying to do but after struggling for a while I realized `$elemMatch` will probably not be my friend. Here is a sample document:

```
{
  "field": {
    "abc": {
      x: 0,
      str: "aaa"
    },
    "def": {
      x: 1,
      str: "bbb"
    },
    "ghi": {
      x: 2,
      str: "ccc"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to construct a query that finds documents satisfying "field.$.x > 1" or anything to that extent. Basically, the name of the field on the second level can be anything. If `field` was an array, I am guessing `$elemMatch` would work beautifully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know the names of the keys you have to use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) which will transform `field` into an array of three key-value pairs. Then you can run [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to apply your condition on`x` and [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/index.html) to check if any item matches specified criteria:

```
db.collection.find({
    $expr: {
        $anyElementTrue: {
            $map: {
                input: { $objectToArray: "$field" },
                in: { $gt: [ "$$this.v.x", 1 ] }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K71bIxRMFWX)

Comment: Is there a way to specify 2+ conditions? If I try to add more side by side `$gt`, I get `An object representing an expression must have exactly one field`. What if I wanted to query for a range of values?

Comment: Figured it out... it should be like so: `in: { $and: [ {$gt: [ "$$this.v.x", 1 ]}, {$lte: [ "$$this.v.x", 10 ] }] }`